# How to fill form's fields programmatically?

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to write a simple auto-login program in Java. 
The login page is "login.php" (not mine!), and it has the following form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="FormLogin" onsubmit="return validalogin();"> 
 <div class="mainContentTitolo1">Inserisci i dati</div>
      <div class="table">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="th">
               <label for="username">Nome Utente.</label>
            </div>            
            <div class="td">
               <input type="text" name="username" id="username" accesskey="m" tabindex="1" size="20" maxlength="16" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="th">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div> 
            <div class="td">
               <input type="password" name="password" id="password" accesskey="p" tabindex="2" size="20" maxlength="16" value=""/>
       </div>        
     </div>        
         <input type="hidden" name="refer" value="$refer" />        
         <input type="hidden" name="invio" value="1" />        
         <div class="tr">            
             <div class="tdcolspanallcenter">
                  <input type="image" src="../../images/conferma.gif" tabindex="3" alt="Conferma login" onclick="return validalogin();" />
             </div>        
          </div>        
          <div class="tr">            
                <div class="tdcolspanallcenter">Collegati            
                </div>        
          </div>    
      </div>
</form>
```

Unfortunately I can't fill "username" and "password" fields.
I tryed to use a link (with CookieHandler and HttpURLConnection classes) like:

```
https://.../login.php?username=BROWN&password=FOX
```

But only "username" field results filled and I recive wrong Cookies.
In browser "source code" I can see as result:

```
[...]
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" accesskey="m" tabindex="1" size="20" maxlength="16" value="BROWN"/>
[...]
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" accesskey="p" tabindex="2" size="20" maxlength="16" value=""/>
[...]
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean JavaScript, and not Java?

Comment: handling POST requests just using the packages in the SDK is not easy. There are other packages that work better (I've used ones at Apache.org)

Comment: You should _never_, under _any_ circumstance, store passwords in cookies. Especially in plain text. That is a _major_ security risk. If you need a "keep me logged in", you should generate a token for that user, which you can invalidate when ever.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I doubt it. Why would OP mention HttpUrlConnection if they were using JavaScript?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson -  I'm talking about Java: CookieHandler and HttpURLConnection are Java classes!

Comment: @ControlAltDel - Ah, sorry. I thought `login.php`-page was his page. Read it wrong. .)

Comment: @ControlAltDel - I want to use the code on Android and I think that Apache is not supported on the last version...

Comment: @Calaf - Your example `?username=BROWN&password=FOX` is in the URL, which is even worse, in some regards. Sorry about the JavaScript assumption though. Read the question wrong. :) How ever, you should remove the `php`-tag, since it's just HTML you want to manipulate on the loginform (not the actual PHP).

Comment: Well, how should I fill fields? PrintStream on getOutputStream() had the same result...

PS: I removed the php tag

Answer (score 0):

Browsers won't let you pass password field(type) values using cookies or from URL, if they would it would be heaven for bots:).
If you insist on auto filling the password field using a parameter from the URL, then change it to `<input type="text" name="password" id="password" accesskey="p" tabindex="2" size="20" maxlength="16" value=""/>` since anyway every one can see the password in the URL

Comment: The "login.php" page is not mine... I only want to perform login from Java and, for this, I have to fill these fields. There is no way to fil the password field programmatically? Even without using the url...

Comment: what about the browser form auto complete? or if you have the password in a db you can get it from there.

Comment: The page is an online university database: every student have Username and Password obviously different.